# Is it possible to treat dictionary values as objects?

Tags: python, dictionary, timezone

Here is a class that analyses data:

```
class TopFive:

    def __init__(self, catalog_data, sales_data, query, **kwargs):
        self.catalog_data = catalog_data
        self.sales_data = sales_data
        self.query = query

    def analyse(self):
        CATALOG_DATA = self.catalog_data
        SALES_DATA = self.sales_data
        query = self.query

        products = {}
        # Creating a dict with ID, city or hour ( depending on query ) as keys and their income as values.
        for row in SALES_DATA:
            QUERIES = {
                'category': row[0],
                'city': row[2],
                'hour': row[3]
            }
            if QUERIES[query] in products:
                products[QUERIES[query]] += float(row[4])
                products[QUERIES[query]] = round(products[QUERIES[query]], 2)
            else:
                products[QUERIES[query]] = float(row[4])

        if query == 'category':
            top_five = {}
            top_five_items = sorted(products, key=products.get, reverse=True)[:5]  # Getting top 5 categories.
            for key in top_five_items:
                for row in CATALOG_DATA:
                    if key == row[0]:
                        key_string = row[5] + ', ' + row[4]
                        top_five[key_string] = products[key]

            return top_five
        else:
            return products
```

It is being called like so:

```
 holder = TopFive(catalog_data=catalog_data, sales_data=sales_data, query='hour')
 top_hour = holder.analyse()
```

What I want to do now is work with the dates. They come in from an input csv file looking like this:

```
2015-12-11T17:14:05+01:00
```

Now I need to change to UTC time zone. I thought of using:

```
.astimezone(pytz.utc)
```

And now to my question: Can I somehow do so in my QUERIES dictionary, so that when the 'hour' argument is passed to the class I can then execute the program, without changing the following code's structure:

```
if QUERIES[query] in products:
    products[QUERIES[query]] += float(row[4])
    products[QUERIES[query]] = round(products[QUERIES[query]], 2)
else:
    products[QUERIES[query]] = float(row[4])
```

and without adding more conditions. 
I am thinking of something like:

```
'hour': row[3].astimezone(pytz.utc)
```

But this is not working. I can understand why, I am just wondering if there is a similar approach that works. Otherwise I would have to add yet another condition with separate return value and work there.

Answer (score 1):

Got it! The answer to my question is yes: you can use methods in dictionary, just as I tried:

```
QUERIES = {
    'category': row[0],
    'city': row[2],
    'hour': hour.astimezone(pytz.utc)
}
```

What I just realized was that I forgot to parse the csv input into datetime format. So obviously when I try to use .astimezone on string it raises error. Sorry for the long useless post, but I'm still very new to OOP and its quite difficult keeping track of all files, instances and so on ;D Thanks